# No me establece el atributo SRC de una etiqueta IMG dentro de un Fetch

Tags: javascript, html5

El problema es que no puedo establecer la **url** de una imagen llegada desde una api a mi etiqueta *img* en mi HTML con la funcion **setAttribute()**. En el navegador me muestra **undifined**. Cabe destacar que esto pasa dentro de una promesa.

Dicha imagen proviene de esta API: https://randomuser.me/

**HTML**

```js
    var boton = document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", cargarPerfil);
    
    var perfil = document.querySelector("#perfil");
    var img_perfil = document.querySelector("#img-perfil");
    var name_perfil = document.querySelector("#name");
    var email_perfil = document.querySelector("#email");
    
    function cargarPerfil() {
        fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')
    
            .then(res => res.json())
    
            .then(data => {
                let img_api = data.results[0].picture.medium
                console.log(img_api)
                
                perfil.innerHTML = `
                    ${img_perfil.setAttribute("src", String(img_api))}
                    ${name_perfil.innerHTML = `NOMBRE: ${data.results[0].name.first}`}
                    ${email_perfil.innerHTML = `EMAIL: ${data.results[0].email}`}
                `
            })
    }
```

```html
  <body>
        <div class="container my-5 text-center">
            <button id="boton" class="btn btn-dark w-100">Generar</button>
    
            <div id="perfil" class="mt-5">
                <img id="img-perfil" src="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
                <p id="name" class="mt-3"></p>
                <p id="email"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="leerApi.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es que tienes `innerHTML` dentro de `innerHTML`

> `innerHTML` es peligroso ya que permite injection de codigo
>   tambien no es requerido para tu estructura ya que solo cambias el texto
>   te recomiendo usar textContent

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", cargarPerfil);

var perfil = document.querySelector("#perfil");
var img_perfil = document.querySelector("#img-perfil");
var name_perfil = document.querySelector("#name");
var email_perfil = document.querySelector("#email");

function cargarPerfil() {
    var data="";
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')

        .then(res => res.json())

        .then(data => {
            let img_api = data.results[0].picture.medium
            img_perfil.setAttribute("src", String(img_api))
            name_perfil.textContent = `NOMBRE: ${data.results[0].name.first}`;
            email_perfil.textContent = `EMAIL: ${data.results[0].email}`;

        })
}
```

```html
  <div class="container my-5 text-center">
        <button id="boton" class="btn btn-dark w-100">Generar</button>

        <div id="perfil" class="mt-5">
            <img id="img-perfil" src="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
            <p id="name" class="mt-3"></p>
            <p id="email"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Es decir que indirectamente afecto a la etiqueta img de mi HTML?
Si no hubiera explicitado las etiquetas dentro de perfil si estaba bien o también tendría el mismo problema?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y la explicacion. Solucionado. Saludos :)

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo por qué estabas usando templates literales en un `innerHTML` Te lo dejo corregido.

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", cargarPerfil);

var perfil = document.querySelector("#perfil");
var img_perfil = document.querySelector("#img-perfil");
var name_perfil = document.querySelector("#name");
var email_perfil = document.querySelector("#email");

function cargarPerfil() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api')

        .then(res => res.json())

        .then(data => {
            let img_api = data.results[0].picture.medium
            img_perfil.setAttribute("src",img_api);
            name_perfil.innerHTML = `NOMBRE: ${data.results[0].name.first}`;
            email_perfil.innerHTML = `EMAIL: ${data.results[0].email}`;
        })
}
```

```html
<div class="container my-5 text-center">
        <button id="boton" class="btn btn-dark w-100">Generar</button>

        <div id="perfil" class="mt-5">
            <img id="img-perfil" src="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle">
            <p id="name" class="mt-3"></p>
            <p id="email"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No lo entendias porque yo tampoco jaja
Es (Fue) mi primer probada de JavaScript :D. Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo mucho.